# Parsing floats from table into a 2D array

Tags: java, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a file that contains a square table of floats. The file is an example, therefore the number of rows and columns may change in the other files for reading.

I am getting an out-of-bounds exception and can't figure out what the problem is.

```
 while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
       String[] allIds = line.split(tabSplit);
       String[] allFloats = new String[allIds.length-2];
//i do "length-2" because the first two columns in the table are not numbers and are
 supposed to be ignored.

       System.arraycopy(allIds, 2, allFloats, 0, allIds.length-2);
       int rows = rowsNumber;
       int cols = colsNumber;
//i have "rows" and "cols" values already extracted from the file and they return the
correct integers.

       double [][]twoD = new double[rows][cols];
       int rowCount = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {                    
            twoD[rowCount][i] = Double.parseDouble(allFloats[i]);
       }
   rowCount++;
}

             }
```

The table i have looks something like this, but with more rows and columns:

```
#18204     name01     2.67   2.79   2.87   2.7
#12480     name02     4.01   3.64   4.06   4.24
#21408     name03     3.4    3.55   3.34   3.58
#a2u47     name04     7.4    7.52   7.62   7.23
#38590     name05     7.63   7.29   8      7.72
```

When I print `allFloats`, it returns each row in a separate array correctly. I don't understand why I get an error when I try to create a 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Try the following:

```
int rowCount = 0;
int rows = rowsNumber;
int cols = colsNumber;
double[][] twoD = new double[rows][cols];

while ( ( line=bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null )
{
    String[] allIds = line.split( tabSplit );
    String[] allFloats = new String[allIds.length-2];

    System.arraycopy(allIds, 2, allFloats, 0, allIds.length-2);

    for (int i = 0; i<cols; i++)
    {                    
       twoD[rowCount][i] = Double.parseDouble(allFloats[i]);
    }

    rowCount++
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception / first few lines of the error please?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
at packagename.Test.parseFile(Test.java:83)`

83 is the line of `twoD[rowCount][i] = Double.parseDouble(allFloats[i]);`

Comment: What Basim also said. Currently when you go through each line you're resetting the rowCount to 0. So you'll always index into the first array. Edit: If your rows variable is the total rows in the file, you're going to get an indexing error as allFloats is just the columns. Use new double[rows][cols] and in your for int i = 0; i<cols; i++

Comment: now that I changed it to `i<cols;` it doesn't throw an error any more, but prints it like this:
`[[2.67,2.79,2.87,2.7],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]`

Comment: Updated my original answer.

Comment: thank you! as to my last comment - this was because i stupidly put the println statement right after rowCount and before the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the two dimensional double array in every line. I would recommend first generating a two dimensional array holding all the float values for each line the after that iterate back over that array and then parse a double from that.

Comment: Do you mean I should move `double [][]twoD = new double[rows][cols];` outside of the while loop? I am not sure how to generate a 2d array holding all the float values and then iterate back over it. I'm very new to Java so it's not very clear to me.